# How to show a quasi-compact, Hausdorff space be totally disconnected?

Tags: commutative-algebra

This is from Atiyah-Macdonald. I was asked to show if every prime ideal of $A$ is maximal, then $A/R$ is absolutely flat, Spec($A$) is a $T_{1}$ space,further Spec($A$) is Hausdorff. The author then asked me to show Spec($A$) is totally disconnected. I am wondering why, because it is not automatic that a compact Hausdorff space is totally disconnected (consider $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ as one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$, for example). Why can we put Spec$A$ a discrete topology when we know elements $\{p\}$ is closed?

Comment: $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space that isn't discrete. (Also, Atiyah and Macdonald are two people!)

Comment: @ZhenLin: That's precisely what I meant: I do not know how to use the condition they given to prove Spec($A$) must be discrete.

Comment: Who said anything about $\operatorname{Spec} A$ being discrete? It is a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: @ZhenLin: A topological space could be totally disconnected while not discrete! Thanks for the remark. But still - how to prove this?

Comment: @ZhenLin: $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected, but not compact.  A better example might be the Cantor set.

Comment: Any infinite profinite group, e.g. $\mathbf{Z}_p$, is compact and totally disconnected but not discrete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so first, there is a distinction made between quasicompactness and compactness. A topological space $X$ is quasicompact if every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover. The topological space $X$ is said to be compact if it is quasicompact and Hausdorff.

We know the $Spec(A)$ is quasicompact for any ring $A$. If you have managed to show for the above problem that $Spec(A)$ is Hausdorff, then this means that $Spec(A)$ is compact.

***Claim: For a non-unit $f$, the distinguished open set $D(f) = \{p \in Spec(A): f \notin p \}$ is closed.***

Proof of claim: Since $f$ is not a unit, it follows that $D(f) \subsetneq Spec(A)$. Our goal will be to show that $Spec(A) - D(f)$ is open. Let $p \in Spec(A) - D(f)$. Then, $f \in p$. Note that $f$ is nilpotent in $A_p$, since the only prime of $A_p$ is $p(A_p)$. Thus, there exists $s_p \in A - p$ such that $s_pf^n = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $p \in D(s_p)$, and $D(s_p) \cap D(f) = \emptyset$. Thus, $D(s) \subset Spec(A) - D(f)$. Since $p$ was an arbitrary point of $Spec(A) - D(f)$, this shows that $Spec(A) - D(f) = \bigcup_{p \in Spec(A) - D(f)} D(s_p)$ is open, hence $D(f)$ is closed.

Thus, for all $f \in A$, $D(f)$ is a clopen set (simultaneously closed and open).

Now let $C$ be a connected component of $Spec(A)$ with more than one element, say $p_1, p_2$. Since $p_1, p_2$ are maximal and distinct, there exists $f \in p_1$ such that $f \notin p_2$. Then $D(f)$ is a clopen set that contains $p_2$ but not $p_1$. This shows that $C \cap D(f)$ is a proper clopen set of $C$, which contradicts the connectedness of $C$.

Comment: These are nice links related to your question that I found online if you are looking for examples of rings of the type above: http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/boolean-rings-ultrafilters-and-stones-representation-theorem/ and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93289/a-0-dimensional-ring-that-is-not-noetherian